# Iterate over points in QML XYSeries

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to iterate over the points in the Qt 5.5 QtCharts [`LineSeries`](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html) type, which inherits from `XYSeries`.

I tried a simple `for`-loop, but I can't figure out a way to determine the number of points in the series:

```
for (var i=0; i < my_line_series.contentItem.children.length; ++i) {
    // do something with the index
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that none of the following are members of `LineSeries`:

- `contentItem`
- `children`
- `length`
- `count`
- `size`

Alternatively, I could try iterating over the series until there's no point to access at the given index--but the method used to access a point at a given index, `at()`, returns `(0,0)` if the index is invalid, and it's entirely possible that there are real `(0,0)` points in my `LineSeries`.

....So is it possible to do this iteration **in pure QML** (see edit)?

**EDIT:** The underlying C++ type [`QLineSeries`](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qlineseries.html) provides the `count()` method, so it's possible to pass the `LineSeries` QML type to a `Q_INVOKABLE` method taking a `QAbstractSeries*` and get the size that way. This seems like an absurd workaround for a simple problem, though.

Comment: Are you using [this](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qlineseries.html) class?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am using the [QML version](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html), which has an underlying `QLineSeries`, so yes, but not directly.

Comment: @NathanOliver As noted in my edit I can get the number of points by passing the series as a pointer into C++ code, but that seems like a ridiculous requirement for this task.

Comment: I have no QML experience so I will not be able to help you out.  I just wasn't exactly sure what you were doing so I figured I would check and make sure it was not something simple as `QLineSeries` has the functions you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Qt 5.9+ (and maybe 5.8?)

There is now a [`count` property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-lineseries.html#count-prop) with this information.

#### Qt 5.7

Per Oxyd's answer, the `count` property existed in version 5.7, but was not included in the documentation.

#### Qt 5.6 and earlier

The QML `LineSeries` type simply does not provide access to the methods that are required for any non-trivial tasks involving the series.

The solution is to implement these tasks in C++ by passing the `LineSeries` QML type to a `Q_INVOKABLE` method taking a `QAbstractSeries*`.

Comment: It's a pity that you can't use your own subclass of QLineSeries in QML. You could add your required method there and call it in QML. I tried it and failed.

Comment: @Oxyd's answer about using the undocumented `count` property on a series is a better solution.  I would suggest only using custom `Q_INVOKABLE` methods for truly custom functionality.

Comment: @roundtheworld This answer was originally written for Qt 5.6, which, I believe, does not expose `count` to clients. Also, I am generally opposed to any reliance on undocumented behavior, since it is liable to change. However, `count` is now included in the documentation, so I've updated this answer.

Comment: @roundtheworld Actually, looking back at the original question, it specifies 5.5!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with Qt 5.7.

There is a "count" property (not a function) that allows you to iterate over the points of a LineSeries using the "at" function in QML / JS.

Sadly it is not documented, I made a wild guess and have been lucky but I suppose the property did not exist when you tried with Qt 5.5.

Example :

```
for(var i = 0; i < lineSeries.count; ++i)
    console.log(lineSeries.at(i));
```